# Why won't my MySQL command line dump on an individual table work? (but I can dump a full db)

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I am running WAMP on Windows 7 and accessing MySQL command line to do some MySQL work. I cannot get the commands for dumping a specific table working (note: I already selected the db with USE db_name):

This works perfectly fine for doing a full db dump:

```
mysql> mysqldump -u root -p  db_name > output_db_name.sql
```

**But** I cannot dump a specific table like so:

```
mysql> mysqldump -u root -p  db_name table_name > output_table_dump.sql
```

Goes to

->
->

I tried many variations and I can't get it to output.

Comment: `mysqldump` is a commandline *program*, not a SQL statement.

Comment: on where you are right now, do `ctrl + c`, then type in the command `$ mysqldump -u root -p  db_name table_name > output_table_dump.sql`.

Comment: horse thanks for that clarification. majimboo, your statement resolved it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not experienced with a command-line environment, you should use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It's a free GUI application that runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

To dump a given table in a given database, you can choose the "Data Export" function, and then select individual databases and tables.

[image]

The GUI runs mysqldump for you. The output is that of mysqldump, so it's 100% compatible with any way you could produce the dump at the command-line.